# How do I create Ship-To Addresses within Dynamics 365 Business Central using the REST API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

We will be integrating Customer information from a SQL Database into Business Central using the REST API. While some address fields are available on the Customer API resource, we need to be able to create Ship-To Address information for the related Customer record.

How is this possible using the out-of-the-box REST API? I do not see any API endpoints to support this requirement.

We tried researching the REST API documentation but found no explanations as to how to create Addresses for Customer's within Business Central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the time of writing i.e., Business Central 2023 release wave 2, there is no standard API for Ship-to Addresses.

There are a few options available:

- Create your own API by extending Business Central.
- Use Dataverse as a mediator between Business Central and your SQL database.

  - This is however not something I have experimented with myself.
- You can look into the various options available on Marketplace, that allow you to configure your own API's by configuration.